# Why Jenkins String parameter is null?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I have set one String parameter for Jenkins parametrized job

String: MOV

Default value: 5

But when I log output as `echo: "${MOV}"`, that value is null. 
I tried with single quotes, without any quotes, without dollar sign but every time my value is null.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `params.MOV`:

```
echo "${params.MOV}"
```

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters